# Plotly Python: How to hide grid tick on zero?

Tags: python, grid, plotly

I have the following code and output.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'S1': np.random.randint(10, size=(8, )), 'S2': np.random.randint(3, size=(8, ))})
```

```
fig = px.density_heatmap(df2, x='S1', y='S2')
fig.update_traces(xgap=2, ygap=2, selector=dict(type='histogram2d'))
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='black', xaxis={'showgrid':False}, yaxis={'showgrid':False})
```

[image]

I am trying to hide these white ticks that appears in the plot.
I already hid the grid, but these ticks didn't go away.

PS: Also, I know this question title is terrible, but I couldn't quickly come up with a clear one. So, I also would appreciate suggestions for a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that what is actually being shown is the zero line through the `gaps` created.

[image]

This can be hidden with a simple argument, as in the snippet below.

```
fig = px.density_heatmap(df2, x='S1', y='S2')
fig.update_traces(xgap=2, ygap=2, selector=dict(type='histogram2d'))
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='black', xaxis={'showgrid': False, 'zeroline': False}, yaxis={'showgrid':False, 'zeroline': False})
```